# The best way to run two programs simultaneously in python

Tags: python, multitasking

I'm trying to run two programs simultaneously in python, but the examples I found are always pretty over-complicated. Is there a "best" way to run two programs at once?

Comment: Are you talking about paralle processing?

Comment: Can you provide some examples of code you think is over-complicated, as well as the tasks you'd like to do in each process? As is, this question is pretty vague.

Comment: @Mntfr Pretty much

Comment: You could use tmux.

Comment: The terms "complicated" and "best" are subjective and depends on the use case. Your question would be clearer if you could instead provide your use case, what attempts you made or possible solutions you found, and what concerns you have over those attempts/solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two python programs are once? 
Write a wrapper that starts the two scripts. You can achieve this using the subprocess module.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['python', 'somescript.py', somescript_arg1, somescript_val1,...]).
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for!